# Puppet: Test if Resource is defined, or create it

Tags: puppet

I've been trying to figure out a way to test if a resource is already defined in another file, and if not create it?  A quick example:

```
  if File[$local_container] {
    alert("Testing - It existed $local_container")
  } else {
    file{ "$local_container":
      ensure => directory,
    }
  }
```

However - `File[$local_container]` always seems to evaluate to true.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The better way of doing this is by making use of ensure_resource function from puppetlabs [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib)

It takes a resource type, title, and a list of attributes that describe a resource as parameters.

say you have test case to only create the resource if it does not already exist-

```
ensure_resource('package', 'test-pkg', {'ensure' => 'present'})
```

Comment: This seems much cleaner, passing the checkmark this way.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 15):

Do you mean "test if a resource is already **defined**"? If you define a resource (ie, `file {}`, etc) Puppet will create what you're describing if doesn't already exist (assuming you pass `ensure => present`, of course).

To check if a resource is already defined in the catalog or not:

```
mark-draytons-macbook:~ mark$ cat test.pp 
file { "/tmp/foo": ensure => present }

if defined(File["/tmp/foo"]) {
  alert("/tmp/foo is defined")
} else {
  alert("/tmp/foo is not defined")
}

if defined(File["/tmp/bar"]) {
  alert("/tmp/bar is defined")
} else {
  alert("/tmp/bar is not defined")
}

mark-draytons-macbook:~ mark$ puppet test.pp 
alert: Scope(Class[main]): /tmp/foo is defined
alert: Scope(Class[main]): /tmp/bar is not defined
notice: //File[/tmp/foo]/ensure: created
```

Note: `defined()` is [dependent on parse order](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#defined).

Comment: That "depends on parse order" part makes it almost useless.

Answer (score 3):

Or....

```
unless File["${local_container}"] {
  file{ "${local_container}":
     ensure => directory,
  }
}
```

And do keep an eye on those quotes and curly braces....

Answer (score -3):

simply,

```
file{ "$local_container":
  ensure => directory,
  replace => false,
}
```

Comment: Nope, if the `"$local_container"` file was already defined somewhere else (like say by something that wanted to control the permissions/owner) you can't define the same resource twice.